# Tiny directory on ext4 file system taking up 2024 blocks?

Tags: filesystems, directory, ext4

I have an ext4 file system on my work computer and I came across a directory that is taking up >1 mb of space. There are 7 entries in the directory. The directory hasn't ever contained more than 20 entries.

What is going on here? The directory hasn't given me any problems... yet. Should I be worried?

As far as I know I haven't set up any ACL's or extents on the volume. When I created it I used the default block size of 4096.

```
=[3 dc@work ~/documents/work/foo ]= $ ls -lat -r
[...]
drwxr-xr-x  2 dchurch users    4096 Dec 23 11:53 _old/
drwxr-xr-x  5 dchurch users    4096 Dec 30 17:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 dchurch users 1032192 Jan  2 08:51 account_import/
drwxr-xr-x 14 dchurch users    4096 Jan  2 08:54 ../
=[3 dc@work ~/documents/work/foo ]= $ ls -la account_import/
total 5500
drwxr-xr-x 3 dchurch users 1032192 Jan  2 08:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 dchurch users    4096 Dec 30 17:43 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 dchurch users    4096 Jan  2 08:54 _first/
-rw-r--r-- 1 dchurch users  804852 Dec 17 15:37 ca.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 dchurch users    3495 Dec 17 16:14 slurp.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 dchurch users    3707 Dec 17 16:13 slurp.php~
-rw-r--r-- 1 dchurch users 3769577 Dec 17 15:37 us.csv
=[3 dc@work ~/documents/work/foo ]= $ stat account_import
  File: 'account_import'
  Size: 1032192         Blocks: 2024       IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 804h/2052d      Inode: 4458105     Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ dc)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2015-01-05 04:40:11.629350078 -0600
Modify: 2015-01-02 08:51:06.024793685 -0600
Change: 2015-01-02 08:51:06.024793685 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Comment: I think the size pretty much proves that at one point it *did* contain a bunch of files.

Comment: @derobert The directory would have to have contained ~40,000 files to make it grow to that size. I think it's more likely that something is amiss.

Comment: I did some digging and apparently dirty directories are a known issue on ext* file systems. More reason to use xfs.

Comment: `mkdir foobar; mv account_import/* foobar; rmdir account_import; mv foobar account_import`

Answer (score 1):

4096B is only the initial size of the directory, equal to one sector. If however the amount of data to be stored (*metadata*, which includes file names) grows, so will the size of the directory, without it ever going down again to reduce problems with disk fragmentation:

```
 $ mkdir testdir
 $ cd testdir
 $ ls -lhd .
   drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4.0K Jan  5 18:06 .
 $ for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do touch this_is_a_long_file_name_$i; done 
 $ ls -lhd .
   drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 64K Jan  5 18:08 .
 $ rm this*
 $ ls -lhd .
   drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 64K Jan  5 18:09 .
```

EDIT: this is the same experiment for reiserfs:

```
 $ mkdir testdir
 $ cd testdir
 $ ls -lhd .
   drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 48 gen  5 18:54 .
 $  for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do touch this_is_a_really_long_file_name_$i; done
 $ !ls
   ls -lhd .
   drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 55K gen  5 18:55 .
 $ rm this*
 $ !ls
   ls -lhd .
   drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 48 gen  5 18:55 .
```

And this is for xfs:

```
 $ mkdir testdir
 $ cd testdir
 $ ls -lhd .
   drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 6 gen  5 19:00 .
 $ for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do touch this_is_a_really_long_file_name_$i; done
 $ ls -lhd .
   drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 48K gen  5 19:01 .
 $ rm this*
 $ !ls
   ls -lhd .
   drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 6 gen  5 19:01 .
```

It is obvious that neither *reiserfs* nor xfs* care as much about disk fragmentation, since the directory size, upon deletion of the numerous files, returns to its pristine value.

Comment: I'm wondering how XFS and ReiserFS handle this. They evidently truncate their directories when entries are deleted.

Comment: @amphetamachine See my edit.

Comment: *It is obvious that neither reiserfs nor xfs care as much about disk fragmentation* - That's a pretty arrogant thing to say; there's no reason to think those filesystems don't avoid fragmentation in a way that allows directory truncation.

Comment: @amphetamachine I agree with you, I did not mean to be arrogant, only to stress that this does not appear to be a concern for either fs.

Comment: Also, how terrible a practice would it be if you created a 10GB file, then truncated it to 2GB, only to have `du` report the size as 10GB of unreclaimable space? ext4 does *not* do this so by your logic it doesn't care about disk fragmentation either, or at least only selectively so.

Comment: @amphetamachine You are deliberately misreading my statements.