# Size of a folder with du

Tags: linux, bash, files, filesystems

I have copied a folder using `rsync` including symlinks, hard links, permissions, deleting files on destination et cetera. They should be pretty identical.

One folder is on a USB drive and the other on a local disk.

If I run: `du -bls` on both folders, the size comes up as slightly different.

My `du` supports `--apparent-size` and it is applied by `-s` and `-l` should count the content of the hard links.

How can this difference be explained and how do I get the actual total?

Both file systems are ext4, the only difference is that the USB drive is encrypted.

**EDIT:**

I digged down to find the folders that were actually different, I found one and the content is not special (no block device, no pipes, no hard or symlinks, no zero bytes files), the peculiarity may be having several small files within it. The difference is 872830 vs 881022 of this particular folder.

I also ran `du -blsc` in both folders and the result is the same in this case.

*Some extra details on the commands I used:*

```
$ du -Pbsl $LOCALDIR $USBDIR | cut -f1
872830
881022

$ du -Pbslc $LOCALDIR/*
[...]
868734  total

$ du -Pbslc $USBDIR/*
[...]
868734  total

$ ls -la $USBDIR | wc
    158    1415    9123
$ ls -la $LOCALDIR | wc
    158    1415    9123

$ diff -sqr --no-dereference $LOCALDIR $USBDIR | grep -v identical
[No output and all identical if I remove the grep]
```

Comment: Define "pretty identical" and "slightly different".

Comment: How much of a difference?

Comment: @Kusalananda pretty identical = identical content, user, permissions, timestamp for each file/folder, slightly different = a small amount of bytes in difference

Comment: @Atul 836034841990 vs 836037115270 (the content is then roughly 800GB)

Comment: That's about 2 MB. Are you able to run a `md5sum` over the files and then verify that against the other set?  I wonder if you have a _lot_ of directories that could account for the difference (some filesystems don't truncate the directories when you delete entries)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I think diff should be enough to verify equality (?). In that case diff can't find a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you have copied the files using `rsync` and then compared the two sets of files using `diff`, and since `diff` reports no difference, the two sets of files are identical.

The size difference can then probably be explained by the sizes of the actual directory nodes within the two directory structures.  On some filesystems, the directory is not truncated if a file or subdirectory is deleted, leaving a directory node that is slightly larger than what's actually needed.

If you have, at some point, kept many files that were later deleted, this might have left large directory nodes.

Example:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ ls -ld dir
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  wheel  512 May 11 17:09 dir
```

```
$ touch dir/file-{1..1000}
$ ls -ld dir
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  wheel  20480 May 11 17:09 dir
```

```
$ rm dir/*
$ ls -ld dir
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  wheel  20480 May 11 17:09 dir
$ du -h .
20.0K   ./dir
42.0K   .
$ ls -R
dir

./dir:
```

Notice how, even though I deleted the 1000 files I created, the `dir` directory still uses 20 KB.

Comment: That is quite interesting, I also used `du -bs` and I was able to reproduce what you described. Would be interesting to know what ext4 does.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio I [believe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177568/tiny-directory-on-ext4-file-system-taking-up-2024-blocks) that ext4 behaves the same.  My tests were on an OpenBSD system using its native FFS filesystem.

Comment: @Kusalanada what I meant is how this works behind the scenes: what's the threshold and why it does that.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio Possibly to reduce filesystem fragmentation.  There is no threshold. The directory node is simply _never_ truncated.

Comment: @Kusalananda, nice one! Never noticed this! Is there a way to reduce the disk usage by truncating them?

Comment: @danieldeveloper001 I'm not a Linux user and don't know if there's some specific tool for doing this on ext4 filesystems, but the portable way would be to move the contents of a directory to a new directory and then `rmdir` the original directory.  Or, for a whole hierarchy, use `rsync` to copy it, then delete the original (as the user in the question actually did).

Comment: @Kusalananda, that's fine, in any rate, thank you! I still didn't find anything in this regard and if I do, I will come and post it here, it would be really useful to have such ability.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the filesystem block size? Even though both devices use the same filesystem, it is a possibility that the block sizes are different and this could explain the "slightly different" sizes.

When, for instance, storing a bunch of 1KiB files in a device with filesystem set to use 8KiB block size, there will be a waste of 7KiB per used block. The actual size that your files are taking from your disk, is the size of the used blocks, not the size of the files itself in this case (unless there is some kind of tool to store multiple files per block). Try checking your different devices block size with the command below.

```
# blockdev --getbsz <DEVICE>
```

Comment: Should this not be covered by using `--block-size=1` as a `du` option?

Comment: Just checked they both return 4096.

Comment: Sorry, started writing before your edit ;)

Comment: No worries, it was a good guess.